# Using a placeholder image before loading the full image

Tags: iphone

What is the correct way to use a placeholder image?

I want to fill a UIScrollView with images as subviews, but it has been to heavy on the older devices to load in all the full images before showing the scrollview.

How can a placeholder image be used so that I can load in the full image when the user scrolls to that contentOffset?

I tried using the thumbnail of the ALAsset, but the scaling looks horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you're using UIImageView subviews for your image tiles. At the beginning, you can populate your UIImageView subviews like so:

```
 for each tile location in myScrollView area:
    [myScrollView addSubview:[UIImageView 
       initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]]];
```

The key here is that imageNamed does caching behind the scenes (see the SDK docs), and only one actual placeholder.png image will exist in memory.

In your delegate to UIScrollView events, when user has scrolled and settled on a new tile that doesn't have its content loaded, set off the loading process and replace the UIImageView at that location (remove the placeholder, add the proper one).

Obviously, you might want to unload old image tiles too at some point to save memory.

Comment: Great. With one placeholder image, how does the photos app have a lower quality image of each image and then loads in the correct one? IF you swipe really fast in the photos app scroll view you will see this blurry image which then loads into the full image.

Comment: Oh I see, you want a low res preview? That wasn't clear in your question (but hinted at, I see now). I'm guessing that the photos app stores a low res preview with some sort of filtering going on to make it not look completely horrible (e.g. some sort of blur effect).

Comment: For blurring, check this out: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/uiimage-blur.html

Comment: Thanks. :) How do they get the low res image. Im getting the image from an ALAsset and the only options I see are the thumbnail and the fullScreen or fullResolution image representations.

Comment: They may be getting a low res image by blurring the thumbnail on-the-fly.

Comment: I currently use the thumbnail and scale it, but the clarity is horrible. completely blurred. Not sure what to do here. :(

Comment: Sounds like Apple's code isn't blurring the thumnail then. They probably make a custom blurry low res image to load initially while the full image loads -- think about doing that?

Comment: thats my issue. If the ALAsset has thumbnail, fullscreen and fullres representations, how is a low res image of the fullscreen of fullres image created and displayed as the placeholder?

Comment: And btw, its not that I want a blurry image. :P I would like to be more memory efficient.

Comment: Ah, I'm talking about blurring images because you said "I tried using the thumbnail of the ALAsset, but the scaling looks horrible." -- so I thought you meant you didn't like jagged edges on a blown up thumbnail, if you get what I mean. Not sure where the low res version that the iOS shows comes from then!