# How to assign UIImageView PlaceHolderImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am trying to assign a placeholderimage in my `UIImageView` but am getting this error

> No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector
>   'placeholderImage:'

This is how I thought I might be able to do it... obviously wrong but anyway this is what the code looks like.

```
firstSpaceImageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"CA.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: because there isn't any property/method called placeholder image :)

Comment: All you can do is, first assign=> firstSpaceImageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]; and when you actually want to display image then just use - firstSpaceImageView.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

Comment: okay cheers.. I should have looked in the docs I was working with some example code I found online. Having issues with images in my custome UITableViewCells not display correctly. they said the fix was assigning a placeholder image. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Where did you get the idea of `placeholderImage`? If there was some code like that maybe there's a category .h that you need to include. Something like "UIImage+placeholderImage" perhaps?

Comment: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/9 
third post down.. 2 years old.. but decided to try it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-[UIImageView setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]` is part of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). You need to include it to get this method.

Comment: ahhh, thats why i have not been able to find it anywhere! This goes abit beyond my needs, I am having trouble with my images not loading in my tableviewcells untill I scroll. I found one solution that told me to set the placeholder but I dont want AFNetworking.. thanks for your reply though its saved me from any more searching in the apple docs LOL.. thanks.

Comment: :) maybe you should post the code you use for your table view here (on a different thread of course)

Answer (score 0):

There is no property called `placeholderImage` on UIImage (or on UIImageView).  If you want to make your own placeholder solution, [this question](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152288/using-a-placeholder-image-before-loading-the-full-image&ei=rW02UcSBEey40QHRt4GYAQ&usg=AFQjCNH0RoJQpoJ8X0zyFiuhEztfSfrzoA) will help.

PS: Even if there was such a property, the setter method would be `setPlaceholderImage:` rather than `placeholderImage`